# Is there an OOB way to personalize based on the Search data using Coveo

Tags: coveo

I have a requirement: Implement personalization based on the condition "**If contact has searched for one of the terms X,Y,Z**" using Coveo search

Is there an OOB way to personalize based on the Search data using coveo.

I went through the doc https://www.coveo.com/blog/delivering-search-personalization-with-user-intent/ it seems its possible out of the box but I do not know how.

Can somebody please confirm?